# html footer problem

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

i'm new to html and im having some problems adding a footer. More specifically, when i add the footer, the 'form' gets pulled until it reaches the footer - like this http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jhbw5g&s=7 . How can i stop it from extending the body of the form?

html code

```
<body>
    <div id="formWrapper">
            </center>
          <form method ="post" action="addMember.php">
          <label for="name">Username:</label>
          <input name="name"/>
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input name="password"/>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input name="email"/>
            <p>
            <fieldset>
            <input class="btn" name="submit" type="Submit" value="Register"/>
            <input class="btn" name="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Form">
            </fieldset>
      </form>

     <div class="push"></div></div>
         <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
</body>
```

Stylesheet

```
#formWrapper{
    width:400px;
    border:solid 5px #F1F1F1;
    margin-top:300;
    margin-bottom:10;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #AFC8DE;
    padding-top: 10px;

    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;   

}
```

> html, body { height: 100%; }
>
> .push{    background-color: #903;     margin: 50px; }
>
> .footer {     height: 4em;    background-color: #103; }

More specifically `min-height: 100%;` makes it drag out but unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly your needs are, but for one your footer div is within the form wrapper, so it will follow the height of whatever that wrapper is.

http://jsfiddle.net/7SgGT/
Here is something I quickly put together.  This should get you started on what you're looking for I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of problems in your HTML code as posted.

- a "center" end-tag with no start
- the second "input" tag is not closed
- empty div.push tag?
- the indents look off (maybe due to stackoverflow formatting?)

Please reexamine your HTML and edit the question with updated HTML if the problem does not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS..

```
html, body {margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;}
#container {min-height:100%; position:relative;}
#body {padding:10px; padding-bottom:60px; /* Height of the footer */}
#footer {position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */;
```

}